# Understanding the definition of atlas of a stack over the category of manifolds

Tags: ct.category-theory, stacks

I am reading https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.4160 to understand orbifolds as stacks.

> Definition : Let $D\rightarrow Man$ be a stack over category of manifolds. An atlas for $D$ is a manifold $X$ and a map $p:X\rightarrow D$ such that for any map $f:M\rightarrow  D$ from a manifold the fiber product $M\times_D X$ is a manifold and the map $pr_1:M\times_D X\rightarrow M$ is a surjective submersion.

I fail to understand what this means. I know what is a stack but I am not sure what it means to say a map from a manifold to a stack.

Any clarity would be welcome.

Before giving this definition, he says,

> To keep the notation from getting out of control we drop the distinction between a manifold and the associated stack $\underline{M}$. We will also drop the distinction between stacks isomorphic to manifolds and manifolds.

This only made the definition complicated and not easier (for me) :D

Help me to understand the notion of atlas.

If it helps, I am trying to read about geometric stacks which are defined to be stacks over manifolds which possesses an atlas.

Comment: A morphism from a manifold $M$ to a stack $D$ is a functor from the slice $\underline M:=Man/M$ to $D$ over $Man$, i. e. such that the composite $Man/M\to D\to Man$ is equal to the projection $Man/M\to Man$. Well, more precisely not equal but isomorphic, and the choice of an isomorphism is part of the structure.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Given a smooth manifold $M$, they have an associated groupoid $\underline{M}=\{M\rightrightarrows M\}$... Given any groupoid $\mathcal{G}$, the functor $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow Man$ is a stack.. in particular, $B\underline{M}$ is a stack.. is this what you mean when you say slice?

Comment: Yes, except that not $B\underline M$ but the functor $B\underline M\to Man$ is a stack: according to 3.28 and 4.1, $B\underline M$ is equivalent to $Man/M$, the functor to $Man$ corresponding to the projection $Man/M\to Man$ ($(N\to M)\mapsto N$)

Comment: Yes Yes, I mean the functor $B\underline{M}\rightarrow Man$ is a stack... I understand now @მამუკაჯიბლაძე :)

Comment: The idea is that a stack is locally a quotient of a manifold by some relation. This relation is exactly the Lie grupoid presenting the stack. This is a generalization of  the disjoint product of charts covering a manifold. In this case, the Lie grupoid is the Cech grupoid.

Comment: About seeing $M$ as a stack, use the Yoneda embedding..

Comment: @user40276 Stack (that we are interested) are $B\mathcal{G}$ where $\mathcal{G}$ is a Lie groupoid and (proper etale) Lie groupoid is an orbifold that is (roughly) quotient of a manifold.. Is this what you mean when you say "The idea is that a stack is locally a quotient of a manifold by some relation. " I do not understand "This is a generalization of the disjoint product of charts covering a manifold. In this case, the Lie grupoid is the Cech grupoid"... "About seeing M as a stack, use the Yoneda embedding.. " what yoneda embedding you are referring to? I have added an answer..

Comment: @user40276 can you see and give your comment if I got it correctly or not?

Comment: Yes. The fibered product of the atlas with itself over the stack gives you a Lie groupoid. In the case of a manifold $M$ with atlas $U_i$ you can take  $\coprod_i U_i \rightarrow M$ as an atlas for $M$ as a stack. This generalizes the notion of atlas for manifolds to stacks. About the Yoneda embedding, it's equivalent to your $BM$ after the Grothendieck construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An atlas for a stack $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow Man$ is
>
> - a smooth manifold $X$ and
> - a map of stacks $p:\underline{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$
>
> such that, given
>
> - a smooth manifold $M$ and
> - a map of stacks $f:\underline{M}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$
>
> the fibered product stack
>   $\underline{M}\times_{\mathcal{D}}\underline{X}\rightarrow Man$ is
>   isomorphic to  a stack coming from a manifold and **something extra 
>   happens**.

As we are saying $\underline{M}\times_{\mathcal{D}}\underline{X}\rightarrow Man$ is coming from a manifold, we better give it a name. We denote that manifold by $M\times_{\mathcal{D}}X$.

This has nothing to do with fibered product of manifolds $M$ and $X$, of course we can not talk of fibered product of manifolds with respect to a category $\mathcal{D}$, it is just a notation that the stack is $\underline{M}\times_\mathcal{D}\underline{X}$ is isomorphic to the stack $\underline{M\times_\mathcal{D}X}$ coming from the manifold $M\times_\mathcal{D}X$.

Now, let us come to **something extra happens**.

This fibered prodcut $\underline{M}\times_\mathcal{D}\underline{X}$ comes with projection map $pr_1:\underline{M}\times_\mathcal{D}\underline{X}\rightarrow \underline{M}$.

[image]

Corollary $4.16$ in that article says :

> Let $M,M'$ be two manifolds. For any map $F:\underline{M}\rightarrow \underline{M'}$ of categories fibered in groupoids there is a unique map of manifolds $f:M\rightarrow M'$ defining $f$.

So, for $pr_1:\underline{M}\times_\mathcal{D}\underline{X}=\underline{M\times_DX}\rightarrow \underline{M}$, there is a unique map associated $f:M\times_D X\rightarrow M$ and by **something extra happens** we mean to say this map $f:M\times_D X\rightarrow M$ is a submersion.

Comment: Yes, $f$ should be a surjective submersion. But I think that, to understand the heuristics, the submersion thing is a bit of a red herring. The point is that you want $f$ to be a *cover* in the Grothendieck topology you chose to put on $\mathbf{Man}$. It happens that surjective submersions give a Grothendieck topology on **Man**, but an equally good (maybe even equivalent, considered that in the smooth category submersions have sections...) Grothendieck topology is simply given by families of jointly surjective open embeddings. (...)

Comment: (...)  Now, such a jointly surjective family of open embeddings $\{j_i : U_i\to M\}$ is almost by definition an atlas for the manifold $M$. The "union" map $f:X:=\amalg_i U_i\to M$ is no longer an open embedding but it's still open, surjective, and a local diffeo; and it's essentially the same as giving the covering family $\{j_i\}$ (if you admit non connected manifolds with a lot of components in **Man**, then $\{f\}$ is a honest (singleton) cover for a still equivalent Grothendieck topology, given by -if I'm not mistaken- surjective local diffeos).

Comment: @Qfwfq I think I understand something but not very sure.. you are saying condition on $f$ will vary depending on what Grothendieck topology I chose to put on Man.. I don’t think that article mentions anything about Grothendieck topology on Man, may be as they don’t want to discuss stack over arbitrary categories they did not care about grothendieck topology on Man..

Comment: Yeah, let's say we have a site $(C,J)$, and a stack $Y$ over it. Then we may call $Y$ "geometric" if it has an atlas $f:U\to Y$, i.e. a $1$-morphism of stacks where $U$ is in $C$ and "locally on $Y$" $f$ is in $J$. By the last condition I mean that for every morphism $V\to Y$ where $V$ is in $C$, $U\times_{Y} V$ is in $C$ and the pullback map $U\times_{Y} V \to V$ is a $J$-cover.

Comment: @Qfwfq ok ok. thanks.  Can you give some reference where little more about geometric stacks is mentioned.. something al9ng the lines of what you said.. it looks very reasonable..

Comment: (...) You should think of $U\times_{Y} V$ as a disjoint union of patches of a manifold atlas (in th eclassical sense) and by $f:U\times_{Y} V\to V$ the "joint cover" i.e. the map that on each patch restricts to its open embedding into $V$.

Comment: Ok ok @Qfwfq I think I got it little..

Comment: See also the nLab page: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+stack

Comment: @Qfwfq I just want to confirm one thing... So, here, the Grothendieck topology is given by surjective submersions... Given an object of $\text{Man}$ i.e., a manifold $M$, a cover for $M$ is simply given by one surjective submersion $V\rightarrow M$.Right? I have difficulty in understanding your definition of geometric stack..You said "[---] and the pullback $U\times_Y V\rightarrow V$ is a $J$-cover"... In an arbitrary Grothendieck topology it can happen that a cover may be of just one element... And here we want $\{U\times_Y V\rightarrow V\}$ to be that type of cover which has only one arrow.

Comment: In paper Differentiable stack and gerbes by Kai behrend and Ping Xu, they consider different Grothendieck topology on $\text{Man}$ (they denote this category by $\mathfrak{S}$)... It is in page $5$... "We endow $\mathfrak{S}$  with the Grothendieck topology given by the following notion of covering family. Call a family $\{U_i\rightarrow X\}$ of morphisms in $\mathfrak{S}$ with target $X$  a covering family of $X$, if all maps $U_i\rightarrow X$ are etale and the total map $\bigcup U_i\rightarrow X$ is surjective"

Comment: With this definition we want $\{ U \times_Y V\rightarrow V \}$ to be a cover i.e., the map $U \times_Y V\rightarrow V$ is etale and surjective i.e., it is a surjective submersion...  This is same thing as the condition with other Grothendieck topology..  Can other definition get affected with different Grothendieck topologies? What is the most widely used  (if any) Grothendieck topology on the category of manifolds $\text{Man}$?

Comment: @Qfwfq About your first comment and my edit, I might have mixed up somethings.. Isn't it the case that, projection map $\underline{M}\times_{\mathcal{D}}\underline{N}\rightarrow \underline{N}$ induce a surjective submersion at the level of manifolds, irrespective of what Grothendieck topology I have choosen on $\text{Man}$.. This will make sure that, I get a Lie groupoid $(M\times_{\mathcal{D}M\rightrightarrows M)$.. source, target maps are assocaited projection maps.. so, proj.maps are surjective submersions at the level of manifolds, I dont know if we get source,target maps to be sur. subs.

Answer (score 3):

It is good to have a simple example in mind. An orbifold is a topological space for which each point $x$ has a neighborhood  homeomorphic to the quotient of an open subset of $U_x$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a finite group $G_x$. Here $X$ is $\coprod_xU_x$ and $p:X\rightarrow D$ is the restriction of the quotient map to $U_x$.

To be more concrete, if $D$ is the quotient of a finite group $G$ which acts on the manifold $X$ (with eventually fixed points) an atlas of $D$ is just $X$. To obtain an atlas of the orbifold you just have to blow-up the singularities.

You can also read the first section of my paper *Differentiable Categories, gerbes and G-structures*,  Int. Journal of Contemp. Math. Sciences, Vol. 4, 2009, no. 29-32, 1547-1590, arXiv:[0806.1357](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1357).

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: Verify that the example in the answer satisfies the properties of your definition.

Comment: I was having trouble understanding the notations and definition.. Any ways, thank you for your post :)

Comment: You can have another approach to the subject in the first section of this paper:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1357.pdf