# To check if a stack is coming from a manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, differentiable-stacks

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a stack. An [atlas](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303826/understanding-the-definition-of-atlas-of-a-stack) for stack $\mathcal{D}$ is given by

- a smooth manifold $X$ and
- a map of stacks $p:\underline{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$

such that, for any

- manifold $M$ and
- a map of stacks $f:\underline{M}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$

the fiber product $\underline{X}\times_{\mathcal{D}}\underline{M}$ is represented by a manifold $P$ (i.e., it is isomorphic to stack  $\underline{P}$) and the map $P\rightarrow X$ coming from the projection map $\underline{X}\times_{\mathcal{D}}\underline{M}\rightarrow \underline{M}$ is a smooth submersion.

I understand the set up.

What I do not understand is

1. How do you check if a map of stacks $p:\underline{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ is an atlas for $\mathcal{D}$?
2. How do you check if a stack $\mathcal{C}$ is isomorphic to $\underline{P}$ for some manifold.

Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $M = X$ and $f=p$, so that $\underline{P} = \underline{X} \times_\mathcal{D} \underline{X}$. The Lie groupoid $P\rightrightarrows X$ you get should be proper, in the sense the source-target map $(s,t)\colon P\to X\times X$ is a proper map, and $(s,t)$ should be injective, so that there are no nontrivial automorphism groups. Then your original stack is the stack associated to the manifold that is the quotient of $X$ by the equivalence relation corresponding to $P$ (which is closed, by properness of $(s,t)$), i.e. $\mathcal{D} \simeq \underline{X/P}$.

---

To respond to the question about non-injectivity of $(s,t)$ in the comments:

Let us say that the groupoid $P \rightrightarrows X$ has some pair $x,y\in X$ are such that $(s,t)^{-1}(x,y)$ has at least two distinct elements, say $a$ and $b$. Then note that $id_x$ and $b^{-1}a$ are distinct elements in $(s,t)^{-1}(x,x)=\mathrm{Aut}(x)$. Then consider the groupoid of functors $\ast \to (P\rightrightarrows X)$ and natural isomorphisms, which is equivalent to the groupoid of functors $\ast \to \mathcal{D}$ (this is because every principal $(P \rightrightarrows X)$-bundle over $\ast$ has a section - this is a nice exercise to work out the details). But by Yoneda the groupoid of functors $\ast \to \mathcal{D}$ is equivalent to the groupoid $\mathcal{D}(\ast)$, thinking of $\mathcal{D}$ as a functor $\mathbf{Mfld}^\mathrm{op}\to \mathbf{Gpd}$. But in the groupoid of functors $\ast\to (P\rightrightarrows X)$ the functor sending $\ast$ to $x\in X$ has a nontrivial automorphism, given by $b^{-1}a$, so the groupoid $\mathcal{D}(\ast)$ has an object with a nontrivial automorphism, hence $\mathcal{D}\colon \mathbf{Mfld}^\mathrm{op}\to \mathbf{Gpd}$ doesn't factor through $\mathbf{Set}\hookrightarrow \mathbf{Gpd}$. Every stack arising from a manifold is in fact a sheaf $\mathbf{Mfld}^\mathrm{op}\to \mathbf{Set}$, so in this case $\mathcal{D}$ cannot be the stack associated to a manifold. Hence for $\mathcal{D}$ to come from a manifold, $(s,t)$ must be injective. This is not sufficient, one really does need properness else the quotient $X/P$, which should be the manifold in question, will not exist in $\mathbf{Mfld}$. Consider for instance the action groupoid associated to a [free action of $\mathbb{R}$ on a torus $U(1)^2$ with irrational slope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_flow_on_the_torus#Applications).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to understand this.. Question is, given a geometric stack $\mathcal{D}$, how do you know if that stack comes from a manifold.. What you are saying is, take an atlas for $\mathcal{D}$ say $X\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ and consider fiber product with itself, giving a stack, which we know is coming from a manifold, you are naming it $P$. You get a Lie groupoid $P\rightrightarrows X$..

Comment: **If the map $(s,t)$ is proper and injective**, then you are saying $\mathcal{D}$ comes from manifold $X/P$ where the relation is $x\sim y$ if there exists $p\in P$ such that $(s,t)(p)=(x,y)$..  Am I correct?? How did you think of this? Can you give some reference.. please..

Comment: The geometric stack is equivalent to a manifold if the Lie groupoid I gave is equivalent to a manifold in the sense in my 2012 paper. (This is because the 2-categories of geometric stacks and internal groupoids with anafunctors as maps are equivalent.) That is the case precisely when (s,t) is injective and the quotient of the resulting equivalence relation is a manifold. This is the case precisely when (s,t) is closed (then properness comes for free), a result going back to Godement, I believe (see eg https://math.stackexchange.com/q/496571/3835 )

Comment: Also, if (s,t) is not injective you know instantly that you don't have a manifold as then you have genuinely stacky points.

Comment: Oh, ok ok.. Can you tell me title of your 2012 paper.. there seem to be two...

Comment: @DavidRoberts: as an aside: do you mind retagging this question with some appropriate top-order (arxiv) tags? Currently it is only tagged [[stacks]].

Comment: @Praphulla Sorry, I thought that would have been clear from the content. It's this one http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/26/29/26-29abs.html (and I forgot the other paper was officially published in 2012!)

Comment: @DavidRoberts thanks for reference. I will see that.. :)

Comment: I am trying to prove on my own the result that you have mentioned... I could not see what Lie groupoid equivalence to manifold is you are referring in that 2012 paper... I have deleted that question $\underline{M}\rightarrow B\mathcal{G}$ being given by a principal $\mathcal{G}$ bundle over $M$ on some one's advice...

Comment: Every manifold gives a Lie groupoid, and ao you can ask what it means for a Lie groupoid X to be equivalent to a manifold M in the localised bicategory, equivalently, what it means to have a functor C(U)--> X that is fully faithful and essentially surjective, where C(U) is the Cech groupoid corresponding to a surjective submersion U-->M

Comment: @DavidRoberts I do not know how I missed your comment. I thought you did not  respond.. By every manifold gives a Lie groupoid you mean the Lie groupoid $\{M\rightrightarrows M\}$ for a manifold $M$, right?? I can ask what it means for a Lie groupoid $X$ to be equivalent to manifold $M$ i.e., I can ask when there is an equivalence of categories $\{M\rightrightarrows M\}\rightarrow X$.. I am confused why notion of Cech groupoid is coming here...

Comment: @DavidRoberts Suppose there is a surjecive submersion $U\rightarrow M$ such that the Cech groupoid (submersion groupoid) $\{U\times_M U\rightrightarrows U\}$  is categorically equivalent to $X$ then do we say $X$ is coming from a manifold? Are these two notions,  $\{M\rightrightarrows M\}$ and $\{U\times_M U\rightrightarrows U\}$ same?? I could not see why they are same..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik "By every manifold gives a Lie groupoid you mean the Lie groupoid..." <-- yes. "Are these two notions..." <-- they give the same stack, up to equivalence. This is the whole point of the localisation business, going back to Pronk's work in the 1990s. These Lie groupoids are _not_ equivalent in the usual sense, which is why we want to formally invert some functors if we take Lie groupoids as the objects under consideration. If we only work with the associated stacks, then they are already equivalent.

Comment: It looks very surprising that for any manifold $M$ and a submersion $U\rightarrow M$, though the Lie groupoids $\{M\rightrightarrows M\}$ and $\{U\times_MU\rightrightarrows U\}$ are not equivalent, their associated stacks $B(M\rightrightarrows M)$ and $B(U\times_M U\rightrightarrows U)$ are equivalent... I mean it is not necessary that if say $B\mathcal{G}$ and $B\mathcal{H}$ are equivalent then $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are equivalent, we can only have $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ to be Morita equivalent.. This is some way of saying about Localization I guess..

Comment: I am just saying to get more clarity... I have a geometric stack  $\mathcal{D}$ and I want to prove that it comes from a manifold... I have to choose an atlas for $\mathcal{D}$ say $p:\underline{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$... As this is an atlas, $\underline{X}\times_{\mathcal{D}}\underline{X}$ is a manifold.. Say $P$... Consider the Lie groupoid $P\rightrightarrows X$ that comes from obvious projection maps $\underline{X}\times_{\mathcal{D}}\underline{X}\rightrightarrows \underline{X}$...

Comment: Suppose this Lie groupoid is such that the map $(s,t):P\rightarrow X\times X$ is proper and injective then $X/P$ is a manifold and there is an isomorphism of stacks $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \underline{X/P}$...  I am sorry, I was busy with some thing in last 20 days so could not spend time on this..

Comment: If $(s,t):P\rightarrow X\times X$ is as you have mentioned then, $X/P=X/\sim$ satisfies the condition in the link you have said https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496571/under-what-conditions-the-quotient-space-of-a-manifold-is-a-manifold in answer by  user43208  Thus, $X/P$ is a smooth manifold.. What is not clear is "if (s,t) is not injective you know instantly that you don't have a manifold as then you have genuinely stacky points" I do not understand this.. what do you mean by stack points.. I know it need not be a manifold in this case but could not understand what are stack points

Comment: I accepted this because I think this is very reasonable...

Comment: If (s,t) is not injective then there is an object of the groupoid with a non-trivial automorphism, which is the very hallmark of a non-trivial stack, and the entire motivation for the theory. It also means that that groupoid gives rise to a stack where one of the fibres is a groupoid not equivalent to a set, hence the stack cannot come from a manifold.

Comment: If I write more here.. people say comments are not for extended discussion.. Can we continue this in a chatroom?

Comment: I am not very sure if I understand your category $*$ correctly.. What is $*$ for you when you say consider groupoid of functors $*\rightarrow (P\rightrightarrows X)$

Comment: $\ast$ is the category with one object and no non-identity arrows.

Comment: It looks more clearer now... I have a stack $\mathcal{D}$ and I want to see when this is representable by a manifold... This stack $\mathcal{D}$ gives a Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}=P\rightrightarrows X$... You want to see an isomorphism of stacks $B\mathcal{G}\cong \underline{M}=B(M\rightrightarrows M)$... This happens only when these two Lie groupoids $\mathcal{G}$ and $(M\rightrightarrows M)$ are Morita equivalent (weak equivalent)... naturally you want $P\rightrightarrows X$ to have same properties that of $M\rightrightarrows M$...

Comment: One property is $M\rightrightarrows M$ is a proper Lie groupoid i.e., diagonal map  $M\rightarrow M\times M$ is a proper map... So, you want $P\rightrightarrows X$ to be a proper Lie groupoid.... Isn't it so? I think this is your motivation for asking $P\rightrightarrows X$ to be a proper Lie groupoid... We thus have a proper map $(s,t):P\rightarrow X\times X$... This map gives an equivalence relation on $X$... As mentioned above, the relation is $x\sim y$ if there exists $p\in P$  such that $(s,t)(p)=(x,y)$... This relation is such that quotient space $X/P$ has a manifold structure...

Comment: For Lie groupoid $M\rightrightarrows M$, $(s,t):M\rightarrow M\times M$ is just the diagonal map.. That is injective.. So, you want for $P\rightrightarrows X$, $(s,t):P\rightarrow X\times X$ to be injective map... **So, it is very reasonable to ask for these two conditions namely $(s,t):P\rightarrow X\times X$ is proper and that $(s,t):P\rightarrow X\times X$ is injective**... But, **how do we knew that  these are sufficient conditions to give a weak equivalence $(\mathcal{G}=P\rightrightarrows X)\rightarrow (M\rightrightarrows M)$**??

Comment: You don't fix $M$ in advance. It turns out that $M=X/P$.

Comment: Yes yes.. we don’t have $M$ before.. I did not mean I know $M$ before.. we only know that $P\rightrightarrows X$ is a proper lie groupoid and that $(s,t):P\rightarrow  X\times  X$ is injective.. it turns out that $X/P$ is a manifold and we have an equivalence $\mathcal{G}\rightarrow (X/P\rightrightarrows X/P)$ what I am trying to understand is how do we know these two are sufficient conditions to give equivalence

Comment: Can you give a reference for the proof of the result that $\mathcal{G}\cong (X/P\rightrightarrows X/P)$? Given conditions mentioned above we see that $X/P$ is a manifold... Is the equivalence $\mathcal{G}\cong (X/P\rightrightarrows X/P)$ some random equivalence or is the equivalence coming from pullback of groupoid $X/P\rightrightarrows X/P$ along surjective submersion $X\rightarrow X/P$??

Comment: The quotient map $X\rightarrow X/P$ is a surjective submersion.. We can pull back the groupoid $(X/P \rightrightarrows X/P)$ along this surjective submersion $X\rightarrow X/P$ (page $6$ of Non abelian differentiable gerbes).. So, we have groupoid $Q\rightrightarrows X$.Is it this same as $\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: _Is it this same_ Yes.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. :) reference is not needed now.. :) I can prove for myself...