# Condition on a Lie groupoid to be represented by manifold/group or an action groupoid

Tags: ct.category-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, lie-groupoids

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a Lie groupoid. I am thinking of following  questions.

1. When do we know $\mathcal{G}$ is weakly/Morita equivalent to a Lie groupoid of the form $(G\rightrightarrows *)$ for some Lie group $G$?
2. When do we know $\mathcal{G}$ is weakly/Morita equivalent to a Lie groupoid of the form $(M\rightrightarrows M)$ for some manifold $M$?
3. When do we know $\mathcal{G}$ is weakly/Morita equivalent to a Lie groupoid of the form $G\ltimes M$ for some Lie group $G$ acting on a manifold $M$?

It is only reasonable to see what properties the Lie groupoids $(G\rightrightarrows *), (M\rightrightarrows ), G\ltimes M$ have so that we can say $\mathcal{G}$ should have atleast these properties.

My observations:

1. Given a Lie group $G$, the Lie groupoid $(G\rightrightarrows *)$ is transitive Lie groupoid. Thus, it should be the case that $\mathcal{G}$ is necessarily transitive to be represented by Lie group. Surprisingly, any transitive Lie groupoid is [representable by a Lie group](https://koushik1729.wordpress.com/2019/02/17/transitive-lie-groupoid-is-equivalent-to-lie-group/), more precisely $\mathcal{G}\cong \mathcal{G}_x$ (isotropy group) for any $x\in \mathcal{G}_0$ . I do not know if we can say anything more in this. Is there any other characterization? Can we say anything more?
2. For a manifold $M$, the Lie groupoid $(M\rightrightarrows M)$ is a proper Lie groupoid simply because, $(s,t):M\rightarrow M\times M$ is the diagonal map which is a proper map. So, $(M\rightrightarrows M)$ is a proper Lie groupoid. If we want $\mathcal{G}$ to be represented by manifold, we should have atleast this condition that $\mathcal{G}=(P\rightrightarrows X)$ is a proper Lie groupoid i.e., $(s,t):P\rightarrow X\times X$ is a proper map. For manifold $M$, $(s,t):M\rightarrow M\times M $ is injective. If we want $\mathcal{G}$ to be represented by manifold, we should have atleast this condition that $\mathcal{G}=(P\rightrightarrows X)$ is such that $(s,t):P\rightarrow X\times X$ is injective. David Roberts says [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308306/to-check-if-a-stack-is-coming-from-a-manifold) that, assuming  that $(s,t):P\rightarrow X\times X$ is proper and injective sufficient to  confirm $\mathcal{G}\cong X/P$ (Any quick proof for this is also welcome). Are there any other characterization?   How do we know where to stop looking at properties for characterization? I mean how do we guess (before proving) that $(s,t)$ is proper and injective then, $\mathcal{G}$ is represented by manifold. Why **proper, injective** determining "manifoldness" of Lie groupoid?

Are there similar characterizations for a Lie groupoid to be a translation groupoid i.e., of the form $G\ltimes M$ for some Lie group $G$ acting on manifold $M$? It is observed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303183/proper-and-etale-groupoid-is-locally-a-translation-groupoid) that, if a Lie groupoid is proper and etale, then $\mathcal{G}$ is *locally* a translation groupoid. Are there any characterization for whole Lie groupoid to be translation groupoid? What should we look for in a Lie groupoid to expect it to be a translation groupoid?

Comment: I have conjectured a long time ago that every compact orbifold is (Morita equivalent to) a quotient of a manifold by a compact Lie group. See my PhD thesis available at http://andreghenriques.com/thesiswarning.html. I strongly believe that this conjecture is true. But my understanding is that this conjecture is still open. Note that, for effective orbifolds, the statement is very easy to prove as the total space of the frame bundle is then a manifold.

Comment: @André I guess by orbifold you mean a proper étale Lie groupoid, as opposed to the traditional definition?

Comment: "is sufficient to confirm" <--- I guess you are missing "is injective" just before this phrase. Also, "proper" includes the condition/implies the map is closed (depending on which of the equivalent def'ns of proper you take)

Comment: @DavidRoberts that is by mistake. I wan to say proper and injective, not proper and closed... :) I do not know what Is traditional definition but I read  Orbifold is Proper etale lie groupoid.. By traditional definition you mean orbifold as topological space with extra properties??

Comment: I would take the traditional definition to include the effectivity condition, whether one uses spaces with orbifold charts, or Lie groupoids.

Comment: @AndréHenriques you said in page 93 before section $6.3$  “So we have also **proven** that every compact
orbifold is the quotient of a compact manifold by a compact Lie group.” You are saying the conjecture is still open.. I don’t know what is that I am misunderstanding... by compact Orbifold you mean a proper etale Lie groupoid whose vase space is compact.. Is that it?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Did you read the warning he wrote on the page he linked?

Comment: @S.Carnahan you mean “I have some ideas on how to fix the whole thing, but if you're looking for a rigorous proof, you'll be disappointed” and “It's mostly correct except for a couple of places where there are problems with the small object argument. ”?.. I understand.. I did not read the warning :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I have deleted your request for current status, because it is already answered in André's comment.

Comment: @S.Carnahan :O current status does not mean just knowing if it is open or not... I was expecting  something about if he knows any one working on that or some related information... I did not feel good that you have deleted my comment... But, that is ok.. I do not know if there is any other reason, so I do not want to take it personally :) :)

Comment: @Prapulla Koushik. Yes, despite what is written in that section, the conjecture is still open. I have spent a large amount of time and energy in the years following my PhD trying to complete the proof. But I have not succeeded. It's now time for others to try to do what I have failed to achieve. (And I'm of course happy to offer advice to whoever wishes to try)

Comment: @AndréHenriques I hope some one (including me :)) can achieve that some day.. I will read what is written in your thesis first and then ask you more questions :) :)