# Atlas of gerbe over stack

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, differentiable-stacks

Suppose $F:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathcal{Y}$ is gerbe over stack and $p:X\rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ is an atlas   $\mathcal{X}$.

Does this imply $F\circ p:X\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ is an atlas for $\mathcal{Y}$?

Atlas of a stack is as in [Understanding the definition of atlas of a stack](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303826/understanding-the-definition-of-atlas-of-a-stack)

Gerbe over a stack is as in [Understanding definition of gerbe over a stack](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307123/understanding-definition-of-gerbe-over-a-stack)

Comment: I am ok with yes/no reply for now... I have tried something to say the result is positive..

Comment: When you say that $p:X\to\mathcal{X}$ is an "atlas", does this mean that $p:X\to \mathcal{X}$ is a smooth surjective morphism and $X$ is a scheme? (I assume yes.) If $F:\mathcal{X}\to \mathcal{Y}$ is a gerbe, then it is surjective. Is your gerbe smooth? If so, then the composition $F\circ p$ is a smooth surjective morphism, and thus an "atlas".

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar it seems to be too straight forward in case of algebraic stacks..  it is not so straightforward in geometric stack set up.. if you are aware of what a geometric stack is, I want to explain little more, otherwise I don’t want to bother you..

Comment: I only vaguely know what a geometric stack is. But, in that context, the "only" condition to verify is that $X\to \mathcal{Y}$ is representable, right? But isn't this automatic if the diagonal of $\mathcal{Y}$ is representable? Anyway, this is as far as I can help you probably. Sorry.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar  Ok.. please let me know if you have seen following definition somewhere... I am just trying to imitate the definition of geometric stack.. An atlas is a map of stacks $X\rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ such that the diagonal $X\times_{\mathcal{X}}X$ is a scheme and some thing extra(I do not know how to imitate that condition here)...

Comment: If $\mathcal{X}$ is a geometric stack (so that its diagonal is representable), then an atlas of $\mathcal{X}$ should be  a map of stacks $X\to \mathcal{X}$ with $X$ a "scheme" (or in your case an object of some fixed category). This is maybe not the definition you would find in the literature, but it should be equivalent to any definition in the literature. (Note that $X\times_{\mathcal{X}} X$ being a scheme is equivalent to the rep'ty of $X\to \mathcal{X}$. But, this is automatic if the diagonal $\Delta:\mathcal{X}\to \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{X}$ of $\mathcal{X}$  is representable.)

Comment: I do not understand why you said "If the diagonal $\Delta:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{X} \times\mathcal{X}$ of $\mathcal{X}$ is representable then $X\times_{\mathcal{X}}X$ is a scheme".... Can you please explain this @AriyanJavanpeykar

Comment: If the diagonal is representable, then isn't any morphism $S\to \mathcal{X}$ representable with $S$ a "scheme"?

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Please see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316484/diagonal-is-representable-then-any-morphism-is-representable