# $2$-fiber product is a scheme then map of stacks is representable

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks

Ariyan Javanpeykar said [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308474/atlas-of-gerbe-over-stack?noredirect=1#comment789174_308474) in comments that,

> $X\times_{\mathcal{X}}X$ being a scheme is equivalent to representability of $X\rightarrow \mathcal{X}$.

Context is as in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316484/diagonal-is-representable-then-any-morphism-is-representable?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Suppose $p:X\rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ is representable, then, for any scheme $M$ with a map of stacks $M\rightarrow \mathcal{X}$, the $2$-fiber product $X\times_{\mathcal{X}}M$ is a scheme. In particular, we can take $M=X$ then, $X\times_{\mathcal{X}}X$  is a scheme. Thus, $p:X\rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ is representable implies $X\times_{\mathcal{X}}X$ is a scheme.

Suppose it is given that $X\times_{\mathcal{X}}X$ is a scheme. Then, I want to see that $X\rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ is representable i.e., hen, for any scheme $M$ with a map of stacks $M\rightarrow \mathcal{X}$, the $2$-fiber product $X\times_{\mathcal{X}}M$ is a scheme. I wanted to write something like $X\times_{\mathcal{X}}M=(X\times_{\mathcal{X}}X)\times_X M$. But it does not make sense as there is no map $M\rightarrow X$.

any comments on how to see this are welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not true even if $\mathcal X$ is an Artin stack. For example, let $G$ be a smooth group scheme over the base $T$, and let $\mathbf BG$ be its classifying stack (the category of $G$-torsors fibered over $Sch/T$). Then $T\times_{\mathbf BG}T=G$ is a scheme. However, the atlas $T\to \mathbf BG$ is not representable by schemes in general. An example where $G$ is an elliptic curve over a normal local scheme $T$ of dimension 2 can be found in the article *[Ineffective descent of genus one curves](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04304)* by Wouter Zomervrucht (arXiv:1501.04304).

What is true is that if $X$ is an algebraic space, $f:X\to \mathcal X$ is an effective epimorphism of fppf sheaves of groupoids on $Sch/T$, and $X\times_{\mathcal X}X$ is an algebraic space, then $f$ is representable by algebraic spaces. Indeed if $U$ is any algebraic space and $U\to\mathcal X$ any map, then $U\times_{\mathcal X}X\to U$ is representable by algebraic spaces fppf-locally on $U$ (namely after base change to $U\times_{\mathcal X}X$, where it becomes a pullback of $X\times_{\mathcal X}X\to X$), hence it is representable by algebraic spaces because algebraic spaces satisfy fppf descent (which is a somewhat nontrivial fact, see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04SJ).

Comment: I thank you for your answer. I am only familiar with differential geometric version of stacks.. i am only recently started studying about algebraic stacks... I do not know much about algebraic spaces.. I can not ask you to explain more... Do you know any other easier ways to see in differential geometric set up of stacks?

Comment: Things are even worse in the differential geometric case, since pullbacks fail to exist.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Ok.

Comment: It seems that this is the best one can say about my question...  I did not completely understand as I don’t know anything about algebraic spaces.. I have given bounty and a +1.. I hope I can understand once I read something about algebraic spaces.. Thank you.. I understand first paragraph in your answer.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik An algebraic space is an algebraic stack whose functor of points is set-valued. However, I'm not aware of a way to define algebraic stacks that does not involve defining algebraic spaces first...

Comment: @MarcHoyois Sir, I read https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/notes/moduli-red-harvard.pdf There, author does not define algebraic stack but there section 8 is named algebraic stack.. In that author defines what is called Deligne-Mumford stack.. There author defines (page $11$) a stack to be Deligne-Mumford if diagonal is representable and something extra.. Represenable is by schemes (page $9$ definition $9$)... As the section named algebraic stack and the only special kind of stack he defines is Deligne-Mumford so I thought that is the definition of Algebriac stack...

Comment: But https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/026N defines saying that diagonal is representable by algebraic spaces.. So, I think  I misunderstood something...

Comment: Many sources (including the original paper by Deligne and Mumford) only consider algebraic stacks with a separation condition that makes the diagonal representable by schemes. I guess this was implicit in your source.

Comment: @MarcHoyois so you are saying new definition (another version) of Algebriac stack is that the diagonal is representable by Algebriac spaces instead of schemes... Ok. Thank you. I some how did not get notification that you have written a comment here so I could not reply immediately.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Sir, I have added an answer which says exactly same thing as you said in differential geometric version.. There also extra condition is that the map is an epimorphism...

Answer (score 0):

Following lemma is from Kai Behrend and Ping Xu's paper (page $8$, lemma $2.11$)  [Differentiable Stacks and Gerbes](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605694v2).

> Let $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ be a morphisms of stacks. Suppose given a manifold $U$ and a morphism $U\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ which is an epimorphism. If the fiber product $\mathcal{X}\times_{\mathcal{Y}}U$ is representable and $V\rightarrow U$ is a submersion, then $f$ is a representable submersion.

Take $\mathcal{X}=X=U$ in above lemma. Then above lemma turns to

> Let $f:X\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ be a morphisms of stacks. Suppose that  $f: X\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ is an epimorphism. If the fiber product $X\times_{\mathcal{Y}}X$ is representable and $X\times_{\mathcal{Y}}X\rightarrow X$ is a submersion, then $f$ is a representable submersion.

I guess  relaxing the condition  $X\times_{\mathcal{Y}}X\rightarrow X$ is a submersion conlcudes that $X\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ is representable.

So,

> Consider a  morphism of stacks $f:X\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$. Suppose that   $X\times_\mathcal{Y}X$ is representable. **If further $f:X\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ is an epimorphism**  then $X\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ is a representable submersion.

This is very much like Marc Hoyois's answer which says that adding the condition that the map is an epimorphism (along with algebraic spaces condition) concludes that the map is representable.